# Multiline label in UIView vs UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, xib

I created a custom `UITableViewCell` with two labels and a button.
It behaved perfectly as expected, and looked like this:

[image: Cell working]

Later, I realised I needed to use this particular view multiple places, one of which was not in a TableView. Therefore I decided to delete my cell, and create a custom `UIView` instead - and create an empty custom `UITableViewCell` only containing this custom view - constrained to 0 in all directions.

With the exact same elements and constraints, the `UIView` turned out like this when shown in a TableView as a cell:

[image: view in cell not working]

Everything is identical. `NumberOfLines` is set to `0`, all the constraints are the same.

I also observed something weird, that when I rotated the entire phone to landscape, it turned out like this:

[image: landscape]

This is exactly how I'd like it to look when in landscape.
If I **now** turn it **back** to portrait, suddenly it looks like this:

[image: Cell working]
Now it suddenly looks exactly like I want it to look in portrait.. I just had to flip it to landscape and back to portrait.. Why is that?..

I played around with some variables, among them: `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`, and found that if I set this value to the size of the screen (minus the 16*2px padding) it looks as expected at first launch in portrait. However, I don't want to set this value. There is no magic number in px that will be right. The whole point of this is to get it fit properly on all screen sizes and orientations. I probably *could* re-set the preferred width every time superview's `layoutSubviews` or something is called, but I figured there has to be a solution for this..? Why did it work for `UITableViewCell` and not for `UIView` **inside** a `UITableViewCell`?

I have tried all sorts of `sizeToFit` etc., and don't find any questions or answers that targets this particular difference in UIView and UITableViewCell..

Comment: Can you show me your code

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary There is no code. Everything is set in xibs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is a bit complex but I will try to explain it... When the view lays out, it initially does so independently of its container and then reports its height to the system when the system needs to determine the height of the cell, which happens *before* the cell is constructed. Once the cell exists and the device is rotated, the view "realizes" it's in a cell and constraints itself and reports its height appropriately.

Sadly, this is an issue in the table view system stemming from legacy issues with how cells were originally sized back before constraints existed.

The simplest solution is to put the labels and button back directly in the cell. Another option might be to make your external view a table view cell. You can instantiate a table view cell outside of a table view for that one spot it's needed in. Another option is to implement the table view delegate's tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: method and manually determine the size.

Comment: Is there a secret trick to instantiating a tableViewCell outside the tableView? Been struggling with it for a while. I instantiate the correct cell, but whenever I try to programmatically constraint the cell to anything all the cell's content disappears..

Comment: You have to have the cell in a separate xib file, not in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using following method for table view's height:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

So, Just add all your view's in stack and set **top, bottom, leading and trailing** constraints of `UIStackView` with respect to `UIView` of xib as:

[image]

Comment: This was a great idea - definitely up-voted! It looked like it worked when I did it exactly as you did at first, but when testing it out and changing the text in the body-label at runtime to something really **really** long, longer than in the xib, then the same thing happened :S.. I don't really have time to spend more time on this right now, but will try to investigate further at a later time. I suspect there might be other factors involved. For now, I'll go with the other suggestion - to instantiate the tableViewCell where I need to use it as a regular view.